# Custom styling to ProMotion table cells

Tags: rubymotion

I am working on an iOS app using RubyMotion and the ProMotion gem.
How can I create custom table cells with ProMotion? If I use the built
in table screens I can only use default iOS styling which is not very helpful.

I added this function which is working when ProMotion is not being used.
However, when I use this on a ProMotion screen, it's not firing:

```
def tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)

 ...

end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Promotion has its own mechanism to create table cells.

Have you read this ? https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/wiki/API-Reference:-ProMotion::TableScreen#table_data

You should be able to do what you need :-)

EDIT:

Here is an example to customize the UITableView colors as well as the UITableViewCells.

https://gist.github.com/Arkan/5662905

Comment: Well, how can I add custom styling to a promotion table? Seems I can only use "default" styling.

Comment: I've forked Arkan's gist here https://gist.github.com/AndrewGertig/6038283 and added the ability to really customize a UITableViewCell by stepping into the ProMotion flow and adding to the cell.

Comment: I haven't gotten too far into customization yet but promotion provides this reference which they say is nearly a complete list of options.  :) Not sure if this existed back when you asked the question. Maybe add this link to the answer? https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/wiki/Reference:-All-available-table_data-options There is a specific option for `subviews` which I would assume allows you to put nearly anything you want into a cell without subclassing. That being said, they do indeed suggest that you subclass if you are going to get "crazy" with customizations.

Comment: @AndrewGertig your gist links seems to be broken. You got a few up votes so it must have been helpful...could you re-post your gist?

Comment: @Andrew sorry about that! I changed my Github name and it has broken a few links here and there. This should work:  http://gist.github.com/gertig/6038283

Comment: https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/blob/master/docs/Guides/Guide%20-%20Making%20Your%20Own%20Screens.md

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to eloquently create custom cells, with custom labels without relying on subview which seems kind of jenky. I then use Pixate to style them.

https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/5151e2cf5cbef290ed44